# Fraps own microphone is recording faster than the sound and screen of the pc itself

Tags: audio, microphone, audio-recording, fraps

I am recording with fraps and I recorded a game of 40 minutes and watched it back. I noticed the sound of my microphone is being played earlier then the actual gameplay sound. Like I got a jumpscare and on the video I already reacted before the jumpscare appeared while my friend on skype reacted perfectly timed in the video.

Is this a known problem? Is there a fix for it?
Is there a different kind of recording software which is kind of the same as FRAPS?
Is the problem actually caused by fraps?

It's Fraps 3.5.99 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I also searched this on Google and the same problem is all over the place with many suggestions. Since you didn't tell us any solutions you've already tried, i'm just going to list as many as i can, hopefully one will help you and/or others as well.

Suggestions to try:

1. Reduce the FPS.
2. Change the default format for all playback devices and recording devices to 44100 Hz instead of 48000 Hz.
3. Use something else to record your voice. I suggest Mumble, with TeamSpeak 3 in a very close second.
4. Re-install Video Card drivers, Sound Card Drivers, Chip-Set Drivers
5. If you've overclocked your CPU or the front side bus, downclock it back to normal.
6. Issues were caused by the EPU-Engine. Uninstall it if you have it.
7. Try to record other games, see if you get the same problem, it might only be a certain game that causes the lag mentioned.
8. Don't try to play the raw Fraps file. Encode it then evaluate it.
9. Get or Use a USB Headset.
10. Use a different sound card, or set windows power properties to High Performance
11. Update your BIOS, or re-flash it

You can try to use other programs to record the audio to solve the issue, suggested software:

1. Audacity
2. PlayClaw
3. HyperCam 3

I would personally never use fraps cause it records in raw format and normally have to encode the files later, the large disk space that gets acquired so quickly may cause the the audio to become out of sync (was suggested, but not confirmed) but makes sense to me.

That being said, if you're looking for a THIS IS YOUR SOLUTION, type of answer, according to everything I've personally read, the admins at fraps, don't know how to solve the problem either, so i doubt that's going to happen without trial and error.

Comment: 1. Already tried it.

2. I'll try that. Though where do I change this?

3. Thanks for the suggestion. If nothing works, I'll try mumble or teamspeak 3

4. Already did this.

5. Didn't overclock it.

6. -

7. I got the same problem.

8.

9. I might try this if nothing else works.

10. Changed the power properties to High which didn't fix it.

11 Don't think this would work.


Thanks though. I'll take a look.

Comment: if you don't know how to do any of these, just google it.